# Argument out of Exception unhandled in MigraDoc

Tags: pdfsharp, migradoc

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string saveFileAs = "D:\\Hello.pdf";
        Program p = new Program();
        Document doc = p.CreateDocument();
        PdfDocumentRenderer renderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true, PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
        renderer.Document = doc;
        renderer.RenderDocument();
        renderer.PdfDocument.Save("D:\\Hello.pdf");
        Process.Start(saveFileAs);
    }

public Document CreateDocument()
    {
        // Create a new MigraDoc document
        this.document = new Document();
        this.document.Info.Title = "A sample invoice";
        this.document.Info.Subject = "Demonstrates how to create an invoice.";
        this.document.Info.Author = "Chandana Amarnath";

        DefineStyles();

        CreatePage();

        FillContent();

        return this.document;
   }

void CreatePage()
    {
        // Each MigraDoc document needs at least one section.
        Section section = this.document.AddSection();

        // Put a logo in the header
        Image image = section.Headers.Primary.AddImage("D:\\Cubes.jpg");
        image.Height = "2.5cm";
        image.LockAspectRatio = true;
        image.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Line;
        image.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Margin;
        image.Top = ShapePosition.Top;
        image.Left = ShapePosition.Right;
        image.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.Through;

        // Create footer
        Paragraph paragraph = section.Footers.Primary.AddParagraph();
        // The following one prints at the footer;
        paragraph.AddText("Aldata Inc.");
        paragraph.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        paragraph.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;

        // Create the text frame for the address
        this.addressFrame = section.AddTextFrame();
        this.addressFrame.Height = "3.0cm";
        this.addressFrame.Width = "7.0cm";
        this.addressFrame.Left = ShapePosition.Left;
        this.addressFrame.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Margin;
        this.addressFrame.Top = "5.0cm";
        this.addressFrame.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Page;

        // Put sender in address frame
        paragraph = this.addressFrame.AddParagraph("Aldata-Apollo Inc.");
        paragraph.Format.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
        paragraph.Format.Font.Size = 7;
        paragraph.Format.SpaceAfter = 3;

        // Add the print date field
        paragraph = section.AddParagraph();
        paragraph.Format.SpaceBefore = "8cm";
        paragraph.Style = "Reference";
        paragraph.AddFormattedText("Section Comparator", TextFormat.Bold);
        paragraph.AddTab();
        paragraph.AddText("Date: ");
        paragraph.AddDateField("dd.MM.yyyy");

        // Create the item table
        this.table = section.AddTable();
        this.table.Style = "Table";
        this.table.Borders.Color = Color.Parse("Black");
        this.table.Borders.Width = 0.25;
        this.table.Borders.Left.Width = 0.5;
        this.table.Borders.Right.Width = 0.5;
        this.table.Rows.LeftIndent = 0;

        //************ Before you can add a row, you must define the columns **********
        Column column = this.table.AddColumn("4cm");
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;

        column = this.table.AddColumn("3cm");
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;

        // Create the header of the table
        Row row = table.AddRow();
        row.HeadingFormat = true;
        row.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
        row.Format.Font.Bold = true;
        row.Shading.Color = Color.Parse("White");

        row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Added");
        row.Cells[0].Format.Font.Bold = true;
        row.Cells[0].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
        row.Cells[0].MergeRight = 3;

        row = table.AddRow();
        row.HeadingFormat = true;
        row.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
        row.Format.Font.Bold = true;
        row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Deleted Items");
        row.Cells[0].Format.Font.Bold = true;
        row.Cells[0].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        row.Cells[0].MergeRight = 3;

        this.table.SetEdge(0, 0, 2, 3, Edge.Box, BorderStyle.Single, 0.75, Color.Empty);
    }

   void FillContent()
    {
        string xmlFileName = "C:\\Section.xml";
        XPathDocument xPathDocument = new XPathDocument(xmlFileName);
        XPathNavigator item = xPathDocument.CreateNavigator();

        XPathNodeIterator iter = item.Select("/Hello/*");
        while (iter.MoveNext())
        {
            string name = iter.Current.Name;
            item = iter.Current;
            Row row1 = this.table.AddRow();
            Row row2 = this.table.AddRow();

            row1.TopPadding = 1.5;
            row1.Cells[0].Shading.Color = Color.Parse("Gray");
            row1.Cells[0].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            row1.Cells[0].MergeDown = 1;
            row1.Cells[1].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
            row1.Cells[1].MergeRight = 3;
            row1.Cells[0].AddParagraph(item.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine(name + "\t:" +item);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I am writing code for generating my report in PDF using MigraDoc. I have downloaded the code from PDFSharp site. The following has 3 functions DefineStyles(), CreatePage(), FillContent(). I made changes in function CreatePage(), FillContent(); But when I am running the program I am getting error saying

**Argument out of Exception: 
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.**

In the CreatePage() I added 2 rows and 2 columns to a table. And in the FillContent() function I read my XML file. But I am unable to find where I am crossing my index range.

**SOLVED**

The problem is when I am setting the table.SetEdge(...). I am accessing the columns that I have not created.
Thank u all .. :)

Comment: Cant you set breakpoint and debug every line?

Comment: I have done that many times. But still I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: on which line you getting exception?

Comment: Thank u I got the answer ... it is at position table.SetEdge(...) At this position I am referring to the columns which I have not created.

Comment: @Amarnath - It's good practice to please post your solution as an answer and accept it, rather than editing your original post. If you don't do this, the question looks un-answered and other people might waste time trying to help, or people searching for similar questions might not see there was an answer and so not notice your solution which might have helped them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this step I was setting the rows that are not yet created.

```
this.table.SetEdge(0, 0, 2, 3, Edge.Box, BorderStyle.Single, 0.75, Color.Empty);
```

Instead of 3 which are the number of rows I should use 2.